# Test result chart/graph from release in tfs 2017

Tags: tfs, release, test-results

I tried to show test result from automation test on dashboard but I wasn't able to do it.
In release I have environment which is responsible for running automation tests, I can see test results in release details and in tests runs. In test runs there are a lot of charts that I want to pin to dashboard, unfortunately there is no option in test run. I tried also creating test chart widget etc. directly from dashboard but they are only working with tests running with build.
Is there way to pin test result from release environment to tfs dashboard?
I am using tfs 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the feature is not supported.

For now, we can only [Add a release summary chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-charts-to-dashboard#add-a-release-summary-chart) to dashboard, then you can naviagte to the specific release from the summary chart to see the test results.

Please see [Add charts to a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-charts-to-dashboard) to check which chart/graph are available to be added to a dashboard.

Comment: I already had summary chart but this is not enough for me. Currently I am still looking for way to show test charts on dashboard,

Comment: @KamilLeśniak Just as I said above, there isn't a built-in feature to support that for now. I also researched that and can not find a way or an existing extension to achieve that. So, if you insist on that, you can try writing your own widget. See [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget) and  [Develop Extensions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)

Comment: After many tries I finally have my test result chart on dashboard, I needed to change whole process to achieved it. Firstly I associated automation tests with test cases, secondly I changed Test selection from test assemblies to test plan. Finally I was able to create chart from test suite and pin it to dashboard. It sounds quite simple but I spent days to make it work especially when you use another framework then MS tests.